# Защита опросника от накрутки

Tags: php, безопасность, csrf

Есть сайт с различными опросниками на php.

Необходимо сделать защиту от накрутки голосов.
На сайте должна быть предусмотрены функции:
1. "Посадить поочереди за один комп людей и пройти для каждого опрос". То есть фильтр один опрос-один ip не подойдет.
2. Вставить на любой сайт виджет с опросом.

Какие мысли есть:

1. Генерить token на сервере. Отдавать на страницу и при отправки результатов сравнивать и обновлять token. Это поможет избежать автозапросов на урл с результатами, например, с фиддлера. (или не поможет?)
2. Сделать, чтобы с одного ip нельзя было голосовать чаще чем 1 раз в 10 секунд (или другой интервал времени)
3. Либо сделать возможность голосовать с одного ip только администраторов (к примеру)

P.S. По поводу 1. варианта. token сохраняется в сессию. Виджет с опросом вставляется через iframe. Но в iframe сессия не сохраняется - как быть?

Comment: никто не мешает роботу накрутчику прочитать ваш токен и отправить его. кроме капч надежной защиты ничто не даст. Хотя даже с капчами "надежной" это я погорячился

Comment: @Mike. А такие капчи работают через сессию? Будет работать в iframe? Если да, то можете скинуть пару примеров?

Comment: @Skywave капча от накрутки не спасет, т.к. есть сервисы для её распознавания

Comment: Что же нас спасет?))

Comment: По-моему это невозможно. В общем случае даже ограничение по ip-адресу не поможет

Comment: @Skywave, делайте регистрацию в вашем опроснике с ручной модерацией. При регистрации запрашивайте фото человека с развернутым паспортом на фоне монитора с вашим сайтом. Вот это вас спасет :Р